# Sum of Legendre sequence $S=\sum_{x=0}^{p-1}\left(\frac{x(x+k)}{p}\right)$

Tags: number-theory, exponential-sum

> Calculate the sum of Legendre sequence $S(x):=\displaystyle \sum_{x=0}^{p-1}\left(\dfrac{x(x+k)}{p}\right)$ with $p > 3$ prime number, $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\text{gcd}(p,k)=1$.

I have tried to find the solution but I did not succeed. I would appreciate if somebody could help me. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to find the sum for $k=1,2,3$?

Answer (score 3):

Dropping the term corresponding to $x=0$ and making the substitution $x=ky$, we get
  $$ S(k) = \sum_{y=1}^{p-1} \left(\frac{ky(ky+k)}p\right) =
       \sum_{y=1}^{p-1} \left(\frac{y(y+1)}p\right),\quad k\ne 0. $$
This shows that the sum is independent of $k$. Consequently,
  $$ S(k) = \frac1{p-1}\,\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \sum_{x=1}^{p-1} \left(\frac{x(x+k)}p\right)
          = \frac1{p-1}\,\sum_{x=1}^{p-1} \left(\frac xp\right)\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\left(\frac{x+k}p\right). $$
In the inner sum in the RHS, $x+k$ runs over all elements of $\mathbb F_p$ other than $x$. As a result, the sum is equal to $-\left(\frac{x}p\right)$, leading to
  $$ S(k) = \frac1{p-1}\, \sum_{x=1}^{p-1} \left(\frac xp\right)\cdot\left(-\left(\frac xp\right)\right) = -1, \quad k\in\mathbb F_p^\times. $$

Comment: Why we have to add the substitution x=ky, if so there is a case y is not in Z

Comment: Why $S=\frac1{p-1}\,\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \sum_{x=1}^{p-1} \left(\frac{x(x+k)}p\right)$

Comment: @NguyenThy The point of the first paragraph was that $S(k)=S(1)$ for all $k=1,2,\ldots,p-1$. Therefore
$$S(1)=\frac1{p-1}\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}S(k).$$

Comment: @NguyenThy: I work in the field $\mathbb F_p$, where you can divide by any non-zero element. If you prefer, instead of $x=ky$ you can write $x\equiv ky\pmod p$.

Comment: @NguyenThy: and for your second question: as shown in the first paragraph, all inner sums are equal to each other; therefore, their common value is equal to their average.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a completely different solution that might be of interest.

First note that
$$\sum_{x=0}^{p-1} x^j$$
is $0\bmod p$ for $0\leq j\leq p-2$ (as can be shown by using primitive roots*), and
$$\sum_{x=0}^{p-1}x^{p-1}\equiv -1\bmod p,$$
as there are $p-1$ terms that are $1$ and one term ($x=0$) that is $0$. We also have the identity
$$\left(\frac{x}{p}\right)\equiv x^{(p-1)/2}\bmod p.$$
Now,
$$\sum_{x=0}^{p-1}\left(\frac{x(x+k)}{p}\right)=\sum_{x=0}^{p-1}x^{(p-1)/2}(x+k)^{(p-1)/2}.$$
When this is expanded, every term is of degree $<p-1$ except for the leading term $x^{p-1}$ (with coefficient $1$), so the sum is $-1\bmod p$. As it is a sum over $p-1$ elements of $\{-1,0,1\}$, not all of which are $1$ (this is where we use that $p\nmid k$), so the sum is in fact exactly $-1$.

*To elaborate more on the primitive root idea; if $j<p-1$, let $g$ be a primitive root $\bmod p$. Then

\begin{align}
\sum_{x=0}^{p-1}x^j
&=\sum_{x=1}^{p-1}x^j\\
&\equiv\sum_{t=0}^{p-2}(g^t)^j\\
&=\sum_{t=0}^{p-2}(g^j)^t\\
&=\frac{g^{j(p-1)}-1}{g^j-1}=0.
\end{align}

Comment: Which part do you apply $gcd(p,k)=1$?

Comment: @NguyenThy I've updated the answer -- I was not clear on that before.

Comment: Why each term is of degree < p-1 then the sum is -1, can you explain more? Thank you